# Android Studio "Project Structure" window not working?

Tags: android, android-studio

Loads of tutorials for Android Studio need me to use the "Project Structure" window (File > Project Structure), but whenever I try to open it, I get an error "We will provide a UI to configure project setting later. Until then, please manually edit your build.gradle file(s.)".

Does anyone know if it's like this for everyone (in which case, what do those tutorials mean by File > Project Structure?), or just me? I've had the same error on Windows and Linux.

One of the tutorials: [How do I add a library project to Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-the-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

Before Android Studio, IntelliJ Android plugin users used to use the Project Structure dialog to add/remove modules from their projects.

Android Studio aims to have a single model for building your application from both the command line and from the IDE. So if you have to modify the project structure, the correct way to do it is to modify your build.gradle (and/or settings.gradle) build scripts and reimport the project.

Eventually (within a few months), Android Studio will hook up the project structure dialog to automatically edit the gradle build scripts for you, or will provide a different UI, just like the error message says.

You'll find the gradle plugin user guide at http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide to be helpful in figuring out how to add libraries to your gradle build scripts.

Answer (score 0):

There are currently some bugs with the UI in android studio project structure settings related to updating the Gradle. Right now whatever I enter into the project structure fields do not save or update the gradle files.  What did work for me was writing the settings directly into the build.gradle

The gradle files are basically xml files that are generated (dynamic) instead of static.

I tried forever in the project structure UI to set up application signing for debug, eventually to get it to work I added,

```
android {
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file("debug.keystore")
        }


        myConfig {
            storeFile file("other.keystore")
            storePassword "android"
            keyAlias "androiddebugkey"
            keyPassword "android"
        }
    }


    buildTypes {
        foo {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.myConfig
        }
    }
}
```

The android developers guide for configuring gradle will help you get up to speed.
http://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html

refer to the Gradle documentation for the parameters you are looking for
http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide

Answer (score 0):

There are currently some bugs with the UI in android studio project structure settings related to updating the Gradle. Right now whatever I enter into the project structure fields do not save or update the gradle files.  What did work for me was writing the settings directly into the build.gradle

The gradle files are basically xml files that are generated (dynamic) instead of static.

I tried forever in the project structure UI to set up application signing for debug, eventually to get it to work I added,

```
android {
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file("debug.keystore")
        }


        myConfig {
            storeFile file("other.keystore")
            storePassword "android"
            keyAlias "androiddebugkey"
            keyPassword "android"
        }
    }


    buildTypes {
        foo {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.myConfig
        }
    }
}
```

The android developers guide for configuring gradle will help you get up to speed.
http://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html

refer to the Gradle documentation for the parameters you are looking for
http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide